# How can I extract values from a list of an unknown value type?

Tags: c#

I can't seem to figure out how to convert a `orderedDictionary` with values consisting of lists of childinstances and lists of tuples containing childinstances into a list of the childinstances as their parent type (Item) without calling each list type in the `OrderedDictionary` explicitly...

```
//Here is a sample of an entry in the OrderedDictionary           
{ "Contextuals", new List<Contextual>{} },

//and some of the entries are lists of tuples; where the int represents an ammount value of "stacked" objects:
{"Consumables", new List<Tuple<Consumable,int>>{} },
```

So I have a loop that iterates through said dictionary:

(I tried using the type of `object` in place of `UnknownListType` but am not sure if that would be valid since I can't iterate through an object as a list without stating it's explicit type.)

```
//convertedList collects all the childinstances as their base type (Item)
List<Item> convertedList = new List<Item>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, UnknownListType> storedItemCategory in TestDict)
{
   //how would i properly check the value type of an UnknownListType as a list, this is what i would guess would be the way to do it:
   if (storedItemCategory.Value.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].IsSubclassOf(typeof(Item)))
   {
      //now how would i convert "storedItemCategory.Value" into a list of items before concatenating it to convertedList?
   }
   //else... (extracting the instance of a list of type tuple<UnknownChildInstanceType,int> would be here but isn't really needed to explain the problem)

}
```

I'll probably just end up reworking the `Dictionary` itself where the values are always in the same place If no one has an idea of how this could be implemented.

Comment: It might be a good idea to review how you came into posession of this mixed bag of types and rethink the datastructure such that all types in it support a common interface. By using `Tuple<T1,T2>` (IMO the poor man's `class`), you're precluding that possibility.

Comment: Agree with spender's "mixed bag" point. You are looking for [polymorphism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary must be declared somewhere, for example Dictionary<string,TValueList>. Whatever TValueList is, that tells you the type for the loop variable. You have written KeyValuePair<string, UnknownListType> … did you mean that the dictionary actually has type Dictionary<string, UnknownListType> or did you mean that you don't know the type?

My guess would be that the list type, TValueList (or UnknownListType, as you call it), is IList or some other nongeneric type. Then you would simply access that IList and downcast the members to the type indicated by the string key. Something like this:

```
    static public IList<TValue> GetConsolidatedList<TValue>(this Dictionary<string, IList> dictionary)
    {
        IEnumerable<IList> lists = dictionary.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == typeof(TValue).Name).Select(kvp => kvp.Value);
        List<TValue> consolidated = lists.Where( list => list.Count > 0 && list[0] is ValueTuple<TValue,int>).SelectMany(list => list.Cast<(TValue,int)>()).Select( tuple => tuple.Item1).ToList();
        consolidated.AddRange(lists.Where(list => list.Count > 0 && list[0] is TValue).SelectMany(list => list.Cast<TValue>()));
        return consolidated;
    }
```

Note here I am suggesting to use ValueTuple instead of Tuple. This is more efficient and also enables naming the elements of the tuple for example in the syntax (TValue value, int count)

Having said all that, it seems to me that you would be better off using more type information in the structure. It might make sense to have two dictionaries, one of type Dictionary<string,IList<IValue>> and another of type Dictionary<string,IList<(IValue, int)>>, then have your classes implement interface IValue. If you need to deal with the two dictionaries as one then just put them both into a single class that implements the desired operations.

Comment: It's because the function wouldn't know what type of list would be at each dictionary entry value and object doesn't seem like it would work for the reasons described in the question, there is no actual "UnknownListType" object. I tested using a method with a non-generic type but there'd have to be 'a non-generic type within a non-generic type' in order to compensate that the TValue could == tuple<TItem,int>  or == TItem directly, and i don't see a way to initiate the type of TValue to typeof(storedItemCategory.Value.GetType())  .

Comment: Yes, I thought of that afterward. I have edited the answer above to address this.